# Ubuntu from a flash drive, where do files get stored?

Tags: usb-drive, portable

I'm a total newb to Ubuntu (Linux in general, tbh) and I'd like to try out Ubuntu by running it from a flash drive. Now my question is: Do my files (both installation and 'personal' files (like texts, for example)) store on my flash drive or on my hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

If - when you created the flash drive - you granted space for personal files, Ubuntu will save your personal files up to that limit on the flash drive.
If you didn't, you will have to store them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your personal files will be saved in the USB drive in a file named `casper.rw`. It will be used by the Live Ubuntu session.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a persistence file when you create the live ubuntu disk. Follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) procedure and slide to the right the bar "How much..." until reach the space you want to use. Next time you boot the files will remain where you saved them.